# NullValueHandling.Ignore with JsonConverter::WriteJson

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to perform custom serialisation, all the happy path code works but the null value path is not behaving as I'd like.

I have set the serializer settings to `NullValueHandling.Ignore` and other parts of my object graph that are null (and don't use my custom serialization) have the null values removed. It looks like the Newtonsoft serializer writes to a string builder so we should be able to 'rewind' any written json tokens but I don't see how to not write anything.

Doing nothing and just returning causes the serializer to throw an exception as the json would be invalid.

Any clues?

```
public class SpecialConvertor : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null || (int)value == 0)
        {
            if (serializer.NullValueHandling == NullValueHandling.Ignore)
            {
                //how to make this work?
            }
            else
            {
                writer.WriteNull();
            }
            return;
        }
        // the rest of WriteJson
    }
    // the rest of SpecialConvertor
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem.  1) `NullValueHandling` is for object references.  Since your property is an integer, you probably want [`DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm).  2) If the value is null, `JsonConverter.WriteJson()` is simply not called, and Json.NET itself writes the null name & value.  Maybe you have some higher level converter that is failing to check  `serializer.NullValueHandling`?  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/dWfJ0o for an example of what might be wrong.

Comment: Also, it's possible to serialize directly to a stream, for instance a [`GZipStream`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943899/can-i-decompress-and-deserialize-a-file-using-streams), for which rewinding isn't possible

Comment: @dbc good work, not sure how I missed that. Long day etc. Null check probably from when it was a nullable enum, or lack of trust of the serializer. The call was using value as the default (zero) value, not null. The null i was seeing was mine, that I (incorrectly) wrote out. I'll read the dotnetfiddle in more detail later. Thanks. (Add as an answer if you want credit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`NullValueHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm) is for object references. In your example, your value is an integer.  To omit integer properties with default values, use the setting [`DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm).

The `null` check in `WriteJson()` should not be necessary because Json.NET never calls the converter with a null value.  Instead, it writes the name & null value itself -- or not, if `NullValueHandling == NullValueHandling.Ignore`.  So checking for null and rewinding should never be required.

A null value for an object property might still get written when null value handling or default value handling are `Ignore`  if one of your converters writes it explicitly in [`WriteJson`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_WriteJson.htm).  To prevent that, you can check the settings and skip nulls like so:

```
public class MyClassConverter : JsonConverter
{
    const string Prefix = "My Value Is: ";

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var myClass = (MyClass)value;
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        if (myClass.StringValue != null 
            || (serializer.NullValueHandling != NullValueHandling.Ignore 
                && (serializer.DefaultValueHandling & DefaultValueHandling.Ignore) != DefaultValueHandling.Ignore))
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName("StringValue");
            if (myClass.StringValue == null)
                writer.WriteNull();
            else
                serializer.Serialize(writer, Prefix + myClass.StringValue);
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var s = (string)JValue.Load(reader);
        if (s.StartsWith(Prefix))
            s = s.Substring(Prefix.Length);
        return s;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) { return objectType == typeof(MyClass); }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(MyClassConverter))]
public class MyClass
{
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
}
```