# Could not create an instance of type ITask. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated

Tags: json.net

I have the class structure:

```
public class Task1 : ITask
```

and

```
public class Task2 : ITask
```

and some method:

```
public static T FromByteArray<T>(byte[] data)
        {
            if (data == null)
                return default(T);            
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                return (T)JsonSerializer.Create().Deserialize(reader, typeof(T));                
        }
```

where I pass the interface. And get the error:
"Could not create an instance of type ITask. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated."
I read similar questions, but how can I use the solution with the JsonSerializerSettings in my case?
In my case method Deserialize do not have an option for JsonSerializerSettings

Comment: interfaces are non serializable.

Comment: If your question is *How can I deserialize from a stream using `JsonSerializerSettings`*, then use `JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings)` or `JsonSerializer.Create(settings)` as shown in e,g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32944462/3744182) to [Can I decompress and deserialize a file using streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32943899/3744182).  Or is your problem that you cannot modify `FromByteArray<T>(byte[] data)` in any way?  If so, what can you modify?

Comment: Yes, I solve problem, thank you